# Why does the json code has an other color if it is very long in visual studio code?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am using a JSON file in visual studio code and it is working very good. But if my text (value) is very long, it is not printed in orange like normal, its now white. Why does it is the case and how can I maybe change it back to orange (if it is possible). The functions are still the same.

Comment: there are no functions in a JSON file. Give an example file with the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its the new version. Wait to microsoft fix it or search a new theme. I dont like the new color. Good luck